# AddInstanceForFactory & HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn errors when using SDL2 with Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to make a simple game using SDL2 and C++ on Xcode 11.2.1; however, my progress has been stopped by an error.

All it takes to encounter these errors is simply initializing SDL. Just calling this function will cause the program to crash:

```c++
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
```

Giving these errors:

```
Westerino[16795:847932] Metal API Validation Enabled
Westerino[16795:848288] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
Westerino[16795:848288] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
Westerino[16795:847932] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x102157f00> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
Westerino[16795:847932]  HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine
Westerino[16795:847932]  HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine
```

I have tried [clearing the cache](https://macpaw.com/how-to/clear-xcode-cache), cleaning the build, deleting the preferences, reinstalling the framework, etc. but nothing has helped yet.

It seems like these issues may have started when I updated Xcode, but I cannot confirm that.

Comment: Would this be better off on the game development stack overflow?

Comment: Googling around it looks like the `F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46` UUID & the `HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn` string indicates it might be audio-related; does init-ing only `SDL_INIT_VIDEO` change anything?  Which version of macOS are you using?

Comment: @genpfault I am using Mac OS Catalina 10.15.1. Using only `SDL_INIT_VIDEO` still causes the first three lines of errors and crashing.

Comment: Are you using AudioKit, by any chance? I am seeing the same [plugin] and HALC_ messages in my AudioKit-based project.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue here. I am also using Catalina 10.15.1 and XCode 11.2.1. Although, I managed to build and debug using CodeLLDB in VSCode. Also, turning off "C++: on throw" breakpoints helps to run the program without any pauses.

Answer (score 1):

The message "Metal API Validation Enabled" is harmless and can be turned off easily. Go to Product/Scheme/Edit Scheme, click on the Diagnostics tab, and turn off the "Metal API Validation" option.

Comment: The Metal API Validation stuff is in the Options tab, not the Diagnostics tab, at least in my XCode 11.5.