# Problems with setting up SDL2 for Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

**I am using Xcode 11.4 on MacOS Catalina 10.15.3**

**I use HomeBrew to install SDL2 by Terminal:**
`brew install sdl2`
and then, I open Xcode, create new project named SDL2Tutorial to test the library.

I changed the header search path to 
**/usr/local/include**
and added **/usr/local/cellar/sdl2/2.0.12_1/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib** to Link Binary With Library

In main.cpp I wrote code like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    if (SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and there are a lot of errors appeared including:

**2020-04-02 17:03:41.767966+0700 SDL2Tutorial[829:23149] Metal API Validation Enable**

**2020-04-02 17:03:41.799979+0700 SDL2Tutorial[829:23443] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35**

**2020-04-02 17:03:41.800445+0700 SDL2Tutorial[829:23443] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35**

**2020-04-02 17:03:41.848181+0700 SDL2Tutorial[829:23149] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id  F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46**

**2020-04-02 17:03:41.875838+0700 SDL2Tutorial[829:23149]  HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine**

**2020-04-02 17:03:41.876282+0700 SDL2Tutorial[829:23149]  HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine**

Did I miss any step of setting up the library and how can I solve all of the errors?

Comment: See the second comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983341/addinstanceforfactory-halc-shelldriverplugin-errors-when-using-sdl2-with-xcode).

Comment: I don't know if you figured this out or not but, apparently you can ignore those errors. The only thing is, you need to create an event loop for your windows to be displayed (a timer like in the docs is apparently not enough).